# Newbie: About migration (how does it affect the test database)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, migration, rake

In Rails, if I create & run a **migration** which used to add one new column to a table, then, the table will have a new column in the **development database**.

But, how could the **test database** also be updated/noticed to have the new column in the table ? Do I need to explicitly switch to test environment from console and run the migration again in **test environment**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `bundle exec rake db:test:prepare` after complete migrations on the development database.

Comment: Is it a compulsory step after each migration run (in order to have the same database as development env) ?

Comment: Yes, if you don't make in your test application will just work with old schema and you will catch an errors if tests use new fields.

Comment: I got "Task not supported by 'mysql2'" error when I run the command

Comment: You use rails 2? May be you should update mysql2 gem. https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/issues/83. Or if you use 3.1 try to "rake test:prepare"

Answer (score 3):

You can explicitly run `rake db:test:prepare`, which actually just builds a new test-database from the development schema (so it does *not* run the migrations, but creates a copy from the current development schema).

When running all tests using `rake test` or `rake spec` this is done automatically.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I finally choose to run the following command which just run the migration in test environment.

```
 RAILS_ENV='test' rake db:migrate
```

Comment: This will work but it's more verbose, and less standard, than `rake db:test:prepare`.